# How to set custom error message React Query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am using the useMutation hook to post data to the backend. I need to render the error message received from the backend. I can't seem to destructure the error message correctly.

```
export const postStuff = () => {
    return useMutation(
        async (token) =>
            await axios({
                url: foo,
                method: "post",
                data: { token },
            }),
        {
            onError: (error) => {
                console.log(error.response.data);
                // custom error message received successfully here
            }
        }
    );
};`
```

```
const {
        mutateAsync,
        isError: postStuffIsError, // boolean works fine
        error 
    } = postStuff();

console.log(error?.message) // Request failed with status code 400 but I want my custom error message from the BE
```

Comment: Typically the response from your backend that is an error will be in the `error.response.data` like the first code block.

Comment: If that is not the case for the second code block. I would suggest `console.log(error)` so you can see the structure of the object and see where the backend message is.

Answer (score 0):

The error data, in the same way it happens inside the `onError` callback, will be accessible on `error?.response.data`, not `error?.message`.

Therefore, you can use:

```
console.log("error message:", error?.message);
console.log("error response data:", error?.response.data); // the actual data
```

See [executable codesandbox demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/usemutation-demo-forked-9nmg1j?file=/src/App.js). Relevant code below:

```
export default function App() {
  const usePostStuff = () => {
    return useMutation(
      () => {
        // request below should return 400 due to missing password
        return axios.post("https://reqres.in/api/login", { email: "a@a" });
      },
      {
        onError: (error) => {
          console.log("Mutation Failed:", error);
          console.log(error.response.data);
          // custom error message received successfully here
        },
        onSuccess(data) {
          console.log("Mutation Succesful:", data);
        },
        onSettled() {
          console.log("Mutation completed.");
        }
      }
    );
  };

  const {
    mutateAsync,
    isError: postStuffIsError, // boolean works fine
    error,
    isLoading,
    isSuccess
  } = usePostStuff();

  console.log("error message:", error?.message);
  console.log("error response data:", error?.response.data);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>useMutations() Hook</h1>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          mutateAsync();
        }}
      >
        Execute Mutation here and watch the console
      </button>
      {isLoading && <p>Making request...</p>}
      {isSuccess && <p>Todo added!</p>}
      {postStuffIsError && <p>There was an error! {}</p>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

On a sidenote, you'll see I renamed `postStuff` to `usePostStuff`. It is [an important convention](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#using-a-custom-hook):

> **Do I have to name my custom Hooks starting with “use”?** Please do. This convention is very important. Without it, we wouldn’t be able to
> automatically check for violations of rules of Hooks because we
> couldn’t tell if a certain function contains calls to Hooks inside of
> it.